# Twitter Atom feed blank for one user but not another?

Tags: twitter, feed, atom-feed

I've been pulling the latest tweet via search.atom in Twitter.

```
$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3A" . $username_for_feed . "&rpp=" . $limit;
```

The problem is lately it just started showing no content. I went and looked at different URLs and it isn't showing, only for certain usernames??

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:kevinbacon&rpp=1

That works for me.

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:zesty_one&rpp=1

Here, both accounts have tweets, and when I add `most_recent`, it makes no difference, so I can't see how date has anything to do with it.

Comment: Nevermind, it's because the search API only includes a weeks worth of tweets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search atom feed only goes back 7 days. So if that user with a blank feed hasn't tweeted for 7 days it won't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Atom feed at

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$username.atom?count=200
```